# How to compare two different times in formula

Tags: formula-field, time

So we receive a check-out time which is the date/time field and I want to compare that time to see if it is greater than 12 PM. This will help decide if I need to charge a full day or half-day.

```
DATETIMEVALUE([Reservations__c].Check_out__c ) > VALUE('12:00:00')
```

This is what I have so far. I am doing Process Builder for this condition. The editor says:

> "The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for operator '>'. Expected DateTime, received Number"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The long and short of it is that to compare two things against one another, they need to be the same type.

`DATETIMEVALUE()` gives you a DateTime
`VALUE()` gives you a Number

DateTime != Number, hence your error.

Based on what you're saying, you don't want to be using a DateTime for comparison here, just the time component. You can either try to convert the Time to a number, or your number to a Time. I suspect that either would work, but it'd likely be better to work with Times rather than Numbers here (especially if you end up working on something that isn't a nice, round number).

When working with formulas, you should be looking at [The Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5&language=en_US) help page.

The `TIMEVALUE()` function looks like it'd be suitable for this task (documentation mentions it should be able to take both a DateTime field as well as a text literal)